# Wordpress floating header interfering with page navigation from div to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Wordpress has a floating header when scrolling down the page. One of my pages is very long so I want to give the user an index that they can click to go to different parts of the page.

**For example:**

```
<a href="#Paragraph1">Para 1</a>
<a href="#Paragraph2">Para 2</a>
<a href="#Paragraph3">Para 3</a>

<p id="#Paragraph1">sample text</p>
<p id="#Paragraph2">sample text</p>
<p id="#Paragraph3">sample text</p>
```

The problem is that when the user clicks the Para 1 link the page navigates to the correct spot but the top part of the paragraph is covered by the floating page header. Is there anyway I can trick it so the top of the paragraph is just under the floating page header when the user navigates to the desired paragraph on the page.

Is there anyway the page navigating can happen below the floating header only. Meaning the top of the page is really directly under the header not behind it.

Comment: May be you can try this:   
1- Create html like this :
<a href="#Paragraph1" class="scroll">Para 1</a>
<a href="#Paragraph2" class="scroll">Para 2</a>
<a href="#Paragraph3" class="scroll">Para 3</a>

<p d="Paragraph1">sample text</p>
<p id="Paragraph2">sample text</p>
<p id="Paragraph3">sample text</p>

Comment: Then Add this script:

$('.scroll').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
jQuery('html, body').animate({ 
   scrollTop: jQuery( jQuery(this).attr('href') ).offset().top+200 
}, 1000);
});

//jQuery( jQuery(this).attr('href') ).offset().top+200 (200 is the height of header you can change it accordingly)

Comment: The following solution worked for me: https://pixelflips.com/blog/anchor-links-with-a-fixed-header